# Why is the power factor neglected in the transformer equation?

Tags: current, transformer, ac, inductor

The transformer equation is V<sub>p</sub>I<sub>p</sub> = V<sub>s</sub>I<sub>s</sub> (p is primary and s is secondary). Why is it not V<sub>s</sub>I<sub>s</sub>cos(φ<sub>1</sub>) = V<sub>p</sub>I<sub>p</sub>cos(φ<sub>2</sub>)?

Why do we neglect the power factor in both cases, is it equal to 1? I know input power  = output power, so it makes sense to write V<sub>p</sub>I<sub>p</sub> = V<sub>s</sub>I<sub>s</sub>, where V and I are sinusoidal functions.

For P<sub>avg</sub>, however, we write the RMS equation, so why do we neglect cos(φ)?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is power factor neglected in transformer equation VpIp=VsPs?*

I think you mean \$V_P\cdot I_P = V_S\cdot I_S\$

If that's what you mean it's because the formula is for an ideal transformer with minimal magnetization current and losses hence, the intrinsic power factor is always unity.

In other words, it is the load on the secondary that dictates the relationship between secondary voltage and secondary current and, if this implies a certain power factor then, that same power factor is seen in the relationship between primary voltage and primary current. Thus the power factors in the equation cancel out on each side leaving us with: -

$$V_P\cdot I_P = V_S\cdot I_S$$

Comment: "that same power factor is seen"...."power factors in equation cancel out"
Hi, can you elaborate on this please, how do they cancel out, is there some mathematical reasoning or it is just experimental evidence?

Comment: The power factor of the load produces a certain phase angle between secondary voltage and secondary current AND, for an ideal transformer this phase angle is the same for the primary voltage and current. This is basically what you get with an ideal transformer **else** power-in won't equal power-out. It's maths and the fact that we can only be talking about ideal transformers (given the formula in your question).